# A word for someone who everyone is scared of?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word to describe someone that everyone is scared/frightened of?

**Example 1:**

> The employees are scared to ask the boss to extend the deadline because he is ______.

(the blank would be replaced with something like 'scary')

**Example 2:**

> Our dictator is so _____ that nobody dares to oppose him.

Comment: Maybe quite literally terrorizing?

Comment: an ogre, is what he is.

Comment: I don’t think North Korea’s dictator is a very good example to give. Most people worldwide (i.e., outside North Korea) consider him a joke, a laughing stock. They’re certainly not scared of him.

Comment: If you want to emphasize the unpredictability, you could use [**mercurial**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mercurial).

Comment: The answer depends on what in particular makes people scared of the person. If it is the fury of his behavior, you might use **tempestuous** or **volcanic** or the phrase **a walking time bomb**. If it is his cruelty, you might go with **vicious** or **sadistic**. If it is his lack of regard for normal standards of baseline human respect and obligation, you could try **sociopathic**. If it is his unpredictability, **erratic** might work.  If it is his disconnection from sanity, you might opt for **unhinged**.

Comment: It's hard to find a single word that can be used in both sentences, IMO.  One sentence is about a totalitarian dictatorship; the other, a person with a poor disposition.

Comment: >> that **everyone** is scared/frightened of?  Monster, and monstrous.

Comment: That would be "Trump"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Perhaps ***intimidating*** will work:

> #### Intimidate
>
> - To make timid or fearful; frighten
> - To compel or deter by or as if by threats

*The employees are scared to ask the boss to extend the deadline because he is **intimidating***.

*North Korea's dictator is so **intimidating** that nobody dares to oppose him.*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intimidate))

Comment: If you want something shorter, "[daunting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/daunting)" also runs along these same lines.

Answer (score 14):

I think that intimidating is the best answer, but just to offer an alternative, consider **tyrannical**, defined at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tyrannical) as:

> unjustly cruel, harsh, or severe; arbitrary or oppressive; despotic

It fits nicely in the blanks of both of your examples.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly stronger than *intimidating* is:

**terrifying**

> *adj.* causing great fear or dread; extremely frightening

[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/terrifying)

Answer (score 3):

A relatively simple word which works is ***feared***.

> The employees are scared to ask the boss to extend the deadline
>   because he is ***feared***.
>   That dictator is so ***feared*** that nobody
>   dares to oppose him.

Wiktionary:

> *Adjective*
>   **[feared](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feared)** ‎(*comparative* **more feared**, *superlative* **most feared**)
>   Pertaining to someone or thing that causes great fear in
>   others.

Answer (score 1):

I like **nefarious**.

: flagrantly **wicked** or **impious**; **evil** [Merriam-Webster's]

*His nefarious activities include lying, cheating, and stealing.*

Comment: Hm, *nefarious* doesn't necessarily make people scared of you, though.

Comment: True, but the OP's examples were different from the posted question

Comment: Describing a person (rather than an act, a purpose, an activity, etc.) as nefarious sounds… unusual at best.

Answer (score 1):

I think both **oppressive** and **maniacal** could be used.

Comment: Explanation, please

Comment: Sorry about what happened to you over at Meta. Don't reply as comments are visible from network account.

Answer (score 0):

This person could be classified as a bully.

> bul·ly ˈbo͝olē/ **noun**
>   1. a person who uses strength or power to harm or intimidate those who are weaker. synonyms:  persecutor, oppressor, tyrant, tormentor,
>   intimidator;
>   **verb**
>   1. use superior strength or influence to intimidate (someone), typically to force him or her to do what one wants. "a local man was
>   bullied into helping them" synonyms:  persecute, oppress, tyrannize,
>   browbeat, harass, torment, intimidate, strong-arm, dominate;

Comment: I do believe the OP is looking for an adjective to describe the person. You have given both a noun and a verb, but not an adjective. You should also look at severely formatting this answer for the better.

Comment: @Hank: Got it. Thanks for your input. I suggested "bully" as to facilitate a different creative framework. 'Intimidate' appears to be the pick, but depending on the context of what the OP is attempting to communicate, an alternative frame of reference could be useful. Anyone can use a thesaurus--I believe people ask questions about language or writing in order to expand their own perspective.

Answer (score -1):

**Omnipotent**

om·nip·o·tent
ˌämˈnipəd(ə)nt/
adjective
adjective: omnipotent
1.
(of a deity) having unlimited power; able to do anything.
synonyms:   all-powerful, almighty, supreme, preeminent, most high; More
having ultimate power and influence.
"an omnipotent sovereign"
noun
noun: omnipotent; plural noun: omnipotents
1.
God.

*Definition Complements of Google Search*

Answer (score -1):

Infamous, perhaps?  It's not quite right, since it means famous for being bad, but it could be used together with some other adjective, e.g., "infamously scary"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe *formidable*? The word implies both a wariness of the individual and that said wariness is warranted.

> **formidable** *adjective* inspiring fear or respect through being impressively large, powerful, intense, or capable: '*a formidable opponent*'

Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/formidable).

Comment: Hello, Brad Ford, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. This site tries to be punctilious about citing the sources of definitions and other quoted language included in answers (as I have done retroactively with your definition of _formidable_ above). In future, please provide source information for any content that you quote in answers at this site. Thanks!